# What organelles(parts of a cell) did early cells most likely have?

Tags: biology, xenobiology, biochemistry

I am trying to make fluorine-breathing life, starting from the cells and building my way up.

I first am going to make very early and primitive cells, and for this I need to know what organelles were in early cells.

When I say “early cells” I mean like, before photosynthesis had been achieved, and before mitochondria. And yes, I know that membrane bound organelles came later, so I am more asking what were the different *parts* or those early cells?

Comment: We have plenty of [bacteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bacteria) and [archaea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archaea) living happily right now on Earth. They are [prokaryotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prokaryote) and they do not have any lipid-membrane bound [cellular compartments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_compartment).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this simplest living cell is Mycoplasma mycoides, and organelle wise it is basically just a plasma membrane, DNA, and ribosomes. There is a slurry of proteins and RNA but nothing you would call an organelle.

https://pdb101.rcsb.org/sci-art/goodsell-gallery/mycoplasma-mycoides

Comment: And in general all prokaryotes lack membrane-bound organelles.

Answer (score 5):

It has been suggested that the evolution of the first Eukaryotic cells (responsible for all multicellular life) was a very unlikely freak accident when a bacterial cell somehow got inside an Achaea cell, survived and became symbiotic with it. The bacteria became mitochondria (cell power providers). Mitochondria still have some of their own DNA separate from that in the cell nucleus.

Something similar probably happened to form chloroplasts as well.

But if you are considering "fluorine breathing" then I would not be looking at existing biochemistry. Fluorine is so reactive that no aqueous solutions would survive. Fluorine reacts with water to produce oxygen and hydrogen fluoride removing the required medium of exchange for reactions.

Fluorine would also oxidize amino acids, pyrimidine and purine bases and all sugars right back to CO2. The options for creating delicate, subtle and large organic molecules needed for life with the chemical chain saw of fluorine would be seriously limited.

Comment: + for "chain saw of fluorine".

Comment: had to be done :o)